# Why does Node Js mongoose document deletion does not execute without await?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

So i am novice at Node.js, and have been checking out its mongoose package. I have a mongodb collection with a document with field name = "Test Entry"
I have tried executing a .findOneAndDelete()  method call on a model wrapped within a timeout, wrapped within a function.

One issue that baffles me is why this piece of code

```js
function deleteEntry() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    Test_Model.findOneAndDelete({
      name: "Test Entry",
    });
  }, 5000);
}

deleteEntry();
```

does not delete the entry within mongodb

whereas

```js
function deleteEntry() {
  setTimeout(async function () {
    await Test_Model.findOneAndDelete({
      name: "Test Entry",
    });
  }, 5000);
}

deleteEntry();
```

this one does.

will the mongoose method not execute unless there is a callback made of some kind. No matter if it's for vain?
There were mentions of something similar [in the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) . Does the actual execution of the command occur only when there is a callback/await/then ?

Comment: Actually both example indeed delete doc from database. And there is no different in two examples,  And both example don't return any promises, nor accept callback, So maybe you might reading database before actually document get deleted..

Comment: thanks for replying! I am using mongodb compass to view the db collection and verify the outcomes. Deletion occurs for the latter and not for the former, that I can concretely assert on. And from the documentation my understanding of mongodb query objects is that they have a .then() method and can be passed callbacks. And that Repeated passing of callbacks or using await/.then() on such helper functions can trigger the execution as well. But as you said. Why does not calling this operation NOT trigger the task?

Comment: @Nur as you said so though my first impression was something similar, but the entry stays in place well beyond the codes execution.

Answer (score 1):

*"Why does not calling this operation NOT trigger the task?"* - I think MongoDB driver check if you passed a callback (as argument) or not,  If you didn't pass callback, Instead, It return Promise. So no matter what, You operation will get executed.

Also you should handle `Error` in  `setTimeout` function, Because It don't handle any error or error from any async operation.

Try this example:

```js
let delay = ms => new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, ms));

async function deleteEntry() {
  await delay(5000);
  return Test_Model.findOneAndDelete({ name: "Test Entry" });
}

deleteEntry()
   .then(result => console.log(result))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning you made. Although i understand your viewpoint. The data entry still doesnt reflect in compass unless await is involved. More thanks for the additional pointers! That delay trick will help me loads. :D